# Incorrect number of template arguments with decltype.

Tags: c++, c++11

In the below program when compiling it complains that there should be 2 template arguments but there is only 1.

```
template<typename T, typename U = T, 
    typename = std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<std::decltype(int()), int>::value>::type>
void func(T t, U u){}
```

However the below code compiles,

```
template<typename T, typename U = T, 
    typename = std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<int, int>::value>::type>
void func(T t, U u){}
```

I am wondering what the difference between the two is and how I might make this code compile.

Comment: Well I am wondering why the above doesn't compile. I would have thought that the type deduced by `std::decltype` would be `int`. Running the code however, says that there is only one argument provided to `std::is_convertible` and I am wondering why that is the case and why it's not compiling. Then I would like to know how to make the two pieces of sample code equivalent.

Comment: `decltype` is a *keyword*, so remove `std::`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decltype` is a keyword, not a function; you're confusing your parser. Drop the `std::`.

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a00f86060e7db9f5))

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] next time; that includes `#include`s.

Comment: Thanks, that was dumb.

Comment: @cogle: A bit :P Tell you what, though, that's a piss poor diagnostic; I'm not surprised it threw you.

Comment: Yea, in the code that I working with I used `std::declval` so I just naively assumed that `decltype` was the same way, and just carried that mistake over when I made the example above. Thanks for the help.